# Docker LLB definition not created - target stage development not being found

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile which is able to build correctly:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine AS node_base

FROM node_base as deps
WORKDIR /11PlusProjectFrontEnd
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

# FROM node_base as build
# WORKDIR /11PlusProjectFrontEnd
# COPY --from=deps /11PlusProjectFrontEnd/node_modules /11PlusProjectFrontEnd/node_modules
# COPY . /11PlusProjectFrontEnd
# Expose port
EXPOSE 3000

RUN yarn build

# FROM scratch AS ui
# COPY --from=build /11PlusProjectFrontEnd/ /11PlusProjectFrontEnd/

#start the app
CMD [ "yarn start" ]
```

However, when I try to create create the container via docker-compose up, I get the following error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: target stage development could not be found
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

I'd appreciate any advice/guidance on the issue. The Dockerfile is for the front end of my app which is in react and I have a backend in Java with its own Dockerfile.